# {{variable}} doesn't update the data when .subscribe method is used

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a new-bee to Angular\TypeScript. I followed [this](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) article and tried to show error message when hero id entered in the url was incorrect or doesn't exist, not able to show it on UI but console.log prints the value properly! I might be missing something here.

**hero-detail.component.cs code snippet**

```
    public getHero() {
    this.errorMessage = '';
    this.hero = null;
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
    console.log(`[HeroDetailComponent.getHero] : id = ${id}`);
    if (isNaN(id)) {
      this.errorMessage = `Invalid Hero id!`;
      return;
    }

    this.heroService.getHero(id).subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero, error => this.handleError('getHero', error), this.getHeroComplete);
  }
  private handleError(invoker, error) {
    console.error(`[HeroDetailComponent.${invoker}] : ERROR : ${error}`);
  }
  private getHeroComplete() {
    if (this.hero == null || this.hero === undefined) {
      this.errorMessage = `None of our heroes has this id. Try next one ! :)`;
    }
    console.log(`[HeroDetailComponent.getHero] : Execution complete! ${this.errorMessage}`);
  }
```

**hero-detail.component.html code**

```
<div *ngIf="hero">
    <h2>{{ hero.name | uppercase }} details</h2>
    <div><span>ID : </span> {{hero.id}} </div>
    <div><span>Name : </span> {{hero.name}} </div>
    <div>
      <label> name:
        <input [(ngModel)] = "hero.name" placeholder="name">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

 <button (click)="goBack()">go back</button><br>
<span style="color:red">{{errorMessage}}</span>
```

When the getHero() gets executed, *console.log* prints the error message properly when I intentionally pass the wrong id, but this doesn't reflect on the UI. I'm not sure why. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the error message in handleError method. This will display message in UI.

```
 this.heroService.getHero(id).subscribe(hero => this.updateHero(hero), error => this.handleError('getHero', error), this.getHeroComplete);


private updateHero( hero: Hero) {
    if (hero == null || hero === undefined) {
       this.errorMessage = `None of our heroes has this id. Try next one ! :)`;
    }
    this.hero = hero;
}

 private handleError(invoker, error) {
    console.error(`[HeroDetailComponent.${invoker}] : ERROR : ${error}`);
    this.errorMessage  = "ERROR : ${error}`";
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately handleError will not get invoked as there is no error in executing service call.

Comment: @KarthikDV updated answer, Please check. look like change is not detected in complete method.

Comment: I resolved the issue  - FormsModule was't added , so it wasn't udpating the UI. Thanks for your help anyway!